# Evaluate the limit using L'Hospita's Rule $\lim_{x \to \frac \pi 2^-} (\cos x)^{\tan x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Thanks for using your time on this.

I am stuck and I don't know what to do.
I know we rewrite this using algebra to have an indeterminate form where we can apply H'ospital.

I thought of applying ln to both sides of the function, but I ended up with

$$\ln(f(x))= \frac{\sin x\cdot \ln (\cos x)}{\cos x} $$ but we cant have $\ln(0)$.

Comment: $\ln(\cos(x)) \xrightarrow{x \to \pi/2^-} -\infty$; should be fairly straightforward to make use of this

Comment: yeah, but then we have −∞/0 and i cant use LH

Comment: The "exponential" indeterminate forms are $ \ 1^{\infty} \ , \ 0^0 \ , \ $ and $ \ \infty^0 \ \ . $  Yours is not one of those...  Now $$ \ \lim_{x \ \rightarrow \ \frac{\pi}{2}^{-}} \ (\sin x)^{\tan x} \ \ $$ would be a different story.

Answer (score 2):

As noticed the limit is well defined as $x \to \frac \pi 2^-$ and since

- $\cos x \to 0$
- $\tan x \to \infty$

we simply have

$$\lim_{x \to \frac \pi 2^-} (\cos x)^{\tan x}=0$$

indeed "$0^\infty$" is not an indeterminate form.

Comment: what? is it the full solution? lol

Comment: @FernandoCavendish Yes of course! The form $0^\infty$ is not indeterminate, we don't need to use exponential form.

Comment: @user: Might I suggest that you put quotation marks around $0^{\infty}$? I think this helps emphasise that "$0^{\infty}$" does not refer to a real number, but rather the string obtained when you plug in $x=\pi/2$ to try to evaluate the limit.

Comment: @Joe Yes of course! Thanks for the good suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)\to0$ and $g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to a$, then $f(x)^{g(x)}\to0$ (assuming that $f(x)$ is positive in a punctured neighbourhood of $a$). Here is an informal argument for why this is the case that can be recast into rigorous $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ language: as $x$ approaches $a$, eventually $g(x)$ becomes larger than any given number $N$. Similarly, if $x$ is close enough to $a$, we have $0<f(x)<1/2$. Therefore,
$$
0<f(x)^{g(x)}<\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{N} \, .
$$
Since $(1/2)^N\to0$ as $N\to\infty$, we find that $f(x)^{g(x)}\to0$.

Now, you can apply this theorem to $f=\cos$, $g=\tan$, $a=\pi/2$. (In this case, we are dealing with a one-sided limit, but the theorem works just the same.)

Comment: Nice explanation (+1).

Comment: @user: Thank you :) I upvoted your answer, too.